# Magento 1.7.0.2 Index Management overwriting URL Rewrites

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a slight problem with the Index Management on Magento 1.7.0.2.

I have quite a few custom URL rewrites for categories.

When I re-index the Catalog URL Rewrites it deletes all of my custom rewrites for the categories and sets them back to the system default.

Before re-indexing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGVBA.png
After re-indexing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJvAA.png

Also on a side note, What are the differences between cache management and index management?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Magento is changing those because you didn't change the **id_path**. If you specify different **id_path** value for your Custom Category rewrite, Magento will not overwrite it.

Also what you want to achieve could be done with Custom Url Rewrite. For example:

*request path*: catalog/category/view/id/118

*target path*: 'corporate'

In this way you're making a destination of system rewrite yours start point.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer.
I was already doing what you suggested. It was already a custom URL rewrite. What did you mean by change the id_path? Does a category not only have one id_path?

Comment: the **id_path** is a unique attribute of Url Rewrite itself, it has no direct connection to the category or request path. In your case the **is_path** is `category/118` - which is the exact value of System rewrite id_path. You need to change it to your own unique value if you don't want it to be overwritten.

Comment: @SlayerBirden: could you change 'is_path' to 'id_path' in your comment? Thanks!

Comment: @boot13 that was a typo, but I don't think I can edit that comment anymore :)

Comment: @SlayerBirden: Dang, I keep forgetting. Oh well I suppose your confirmation of the typo is sufficient. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was driving me absolutely bonkers until I figured out a nice little work-around.

1. I create my new object (in my case it was a category for the top nav
2. I go to URL Rewrite and note the ID Path of the new category
3. I delete the system generated URL Rewrite
4. I create a custom Rewrite specifying the ID Path of the deleted object, The request path, and then the path to the desired URL
5. I then go to phpmyadmin > core_url_rewrite and find my newly created custom Rewrite
6. I change the store_id to 0 (not changing anything else)
7. I then go back to Magento and run a reindex.  This creates a new system generated Rewrite with a higher url_rewrite_id (see in phpmyadmin > core_url_rewrite table)
8. I then create my page with the desired path
9. Reindex / flush caches and presto.. my top nav now has a menu item to my new page.