# Magento URL rewrite reverts default system URL after re-indexing

Tags: php, magento, url-rewriting

I have a weird problem with Magento. I have created catalogs and rewrite it to display custom page and product. The rewrites are successful however after re-indexing the default system URL were shown.

These are my steps in URL re-writing:

1. Delete old system URL.
2. Create new URL re-write by selecting custom in the drop-down box.
3. Fill out necessary fields and save.
4. Flush Magento cache.

The problem is that when I try to re-index, the system URL reverts back.

QUESTION:

1. Why is it that the old system URL reverts back?
2. What are the necessary procedures to prevent this to happen?
3. Do I have to stop re-indexing for the entire life of the system?

This is a sample screen shot of my URL rewrite after re-indexing.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 1.7.0.2 Index Management overwriting URL Rewrites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408213/magento-1-7-0-2-index-management-overwriting-url-rewrites)

Comment: are you deleting all entry of old url or specific ? if all then remove it from directly from db. you can find core_url_rewrite table, delete all records from there then reindex do what ever you want

Comment: @sagar umaretiya Yes, I'm deleting the old one and create a custom url rewrite.

Comment: @rodge, After custom url rewrite have you done with reindexing and cache clearing process if not please do that

Comment: @sagar umaretiya Yes, I clear the cache and reindex it however after reindexing it reverts back to default system rewrite.

Comment: Please, post your solution as an answer and mark it solved for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved my problem

Based on this question Magento 1.7.0.2 Index Management overwriting URL Rewrites I discover a good solution.

I back up my database.
I delete all my custom url rewrite that are not deleted after reindexing.
I locate the default system catalog URL rewrite and update Redirect drop down from No to Permanent (301) and save it.
I create new custom URL rewrite.
I create a unique ID Path (catalog/153)
From the default system catalog URL rewrite I copied the Target Path and paste it on Request Path of my custom URL rewrite.
On the Target Path, I pasted the desired Page URL.
Change the Redirect drop-down from No to Permanent (301) and save it.
Finally, I clear my cache and re-index again.
Problem solved!

Every time I re-index, all URL rewrite were not deleted and works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve above issue, follow the below-mentioned steps:

Step 1- Goto Catalog-> URL Rewrite Management and search for id in the ID path column.

Step 2- Open it and change the redirect option from No to Permanent(301). Also, copy the text inside Target Path non-editable field. It may look like this catalog/category/view/id/55.

Then click on Save.

Step 3- Then for redirecting this category page to Custom or CMS page, we’ve to add new URL rewrite.

To do so, Click Add URL rewrite button in Catalog->URL rewrite Management. It’ll take you to Add New URL rewrite screen, where you’ve to choose Custom from Create URL Rewrite drop-down list.

It will then take you to another new page where you’ve to enter ID path, Request Path, and Target Path.

ID path — It must be any unique identifier. It can anything like "test123" or whatever as you wish.

Request Path — It must be the Target path which we’ve copied before catalog/category/view/id/55 in step1.

Target Path — It should be the Custom or CMS page URL Key which you want to redirect. For example Gift.

Then select Redirection to Permanent(301) from the drop-down and click on Save.